# Why is my function working without being called via keybind?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to make a function and keybind so whenever I press "w" the object moves up 15 pixels, but when not only does the keybind not work, the object appears to have already moved up those 15 pixels from it's original position:

````
from turtle import *

# Screen

win = turtle.Screen()
win.title("Runner")
win.bgcolor("white")
win.setup(width=800, height=600)
win.tracer(0)

# Floor
square1 = turtle.Turtle()
square1.speed(0)
square1.shape("square")
square1.shapesize(stretch_wid=0.3, stretch_len=50)
square1.color("black")
square1.penup()
square1.goto((0, -150))
win.update()

# Player

player1 = turtle.Turtle()
player1.shape("circle")
player1.color("red")
player1.speed(30)
player1.penup()
player1.goto(0,-136)
win.update()

# bindings and functions

def playermove():
    y = player1.ycor()
    y += 15
    player1.sety(y)
win.onkeypress(playermove(), "w")
win.listen()


while True:


    win.update()```
````

Comment: `playermove()` is an *immediate call of the function*.  The player was moved up, and the return value of the function (which is `None`) was used as the action to perform when 'w' is pressed.  Get rid of those parentheses, you want to pass the function itself.

Comment: Also I digress but it's not a good idea to do `from turtle import *`.

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate on this?

Answer (score 0):

As @jasonharper mentioned, you need to provide the function itself. Here is the fixed code:

```py
from turtle import *

# Screen

win = turtle.Screen()
win.title("Runner")
win.bgcolor("white")
win.setup(width=800, height=600)
win.tracer(0)

# Floor
square1 = turtle.Turtle()
square1.speed(0)
square1.shape("square")
square1.shapesize(stretch_wid=0.3, stretch_len=50)
square1.color("black")
square1.penup()
square1.goto((0, -150))
win.update()

# Player

player1 = turtle.Turtle()
player1.shape("circle")
player1.color("red")
player1.speed(30)
player1.penup()
player1.goto(0,-136)
win.update()

# bindings and functions

def playermove():
    y = player1.ycor()
    y += 15
    player1.sety(y)

win.onkeypress(playermove, "w")
win.listen()


while True:
    win.update()
```